# Silicone paste vs. silicone grease vs. silicone spray lube

Tags: materials

For purposes of usage in home/auto and light industrial circumstances, what are the differences? What are the pros and cons, and suited uses, of each?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silicone grease and paste are frequently meant the same thing. They are used for lubrication and because they wrap the area of application they protect the parts from rust and elements. When they are used in applications such as plumbing orings they have to be rated food grade, or for electrical uses they have to be rated.

Silicone spray is mostly used as thin lubricant and locked tread breaker.

Sometimes difference in consistency is just to solve access issues. There are sprays of silicone with different properties for different applications which are hard to reach.